# Am I correctly creating in JavaScript a Blob object for .createObjectURL use?

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I am trying to take the response, which is fetched from a `.png` file, and prep it for placement as an image in the DOM using simple JS. But...

```
ready().then(() => {
  fetch(`/images/logo.png`)
  .then(response =>{
    if (response) {
      let imageBlob = response.blob();
      let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
...
```

is giving me...

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at fetch.then.response (fetchImage.js:6)
    at <anonymous>
fetch.then.response       @ fetchImage.js:6
Promise resolved (async)
ready.then                @ fetchImage.js:3
Promise resolved (async)
(anonymous)               @ fetchImage.js:1
```

If I throw in a `console.log(response)`, I can see that I am getting the full response.
And that `console.log(imageBlob)` will return `Promise {<resolved>: Blob(3737)}`.
So where am I going awry?

Comment: `imageBlob = response.blob();` imageBlob will be a **Promise** - read how fetch works - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch - if the function you are in the code sample is tagged `async` - then you can `let imageBlob = await response.blob();` ... if not, then `return response.blob().then(imageBlob => {let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob); etc}`

Comment: no idea what you're on about ... there's nothing to do with page load in your question, nor in my comment

Comment: have you read the documentation I linked to ... **the first example**  actually uses a blob ... so, your code shouldbe something like `.then(response => response.blob()).then(imageBlob => {let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob); ... etc}`

Comment: Use a canvas render it to canvas and then use `toDataURI()` @AnielaMarieWolkonowski

Comment: I guess I don't understand the reason for the `await` if everything has already happened. I'm new to Fetch and very new to Blob.  I thought the way my code is written that fetch was already called and the blob worked as part of the `imageBlob` variable. I'm wrong about that, aren't I and need to go back to the beginning?

Comment: await was if you use async/await ... see answer

Comment: wait wait wait. I understand what you mean now... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

using fetch correctly, response.blob() returns a **Promise** - so, deal with it as you've dealt with the `fetch` promise

```
ready().then(() => {
  fetch(`/images/logo.png`)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(imageBlob => {
    let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
    //...
  });
});
```

or better still

```
ready()
.then(() => fetch(`/images/logo.png`))
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(imageBlob => {
  let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
  //...
});
```

or using `async/await`

```
ready()
.then(() => fetch(`/images/logo.png`))
.then(async (response) => {
  let imageBlob = await response.blob();
  let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
  //...
});
```

Comment: it's more than that - an arrow functions `this` is the `this` from the enclosing context, in many cases this simplifies code that in the past required code like .. `var _this = this` then use `_this` in the callbacks etc ... or `.bind(this)` ..

Comment: Dude, not going to teach you about arrow functions here (as the question doesn't even relate to arrow functions, the OP knows how to use them already) - good documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions ... in fact, MDN is the preferred place for javascript documentation (even google and microsoft think so)

Comment: good :p it should explain all you need to know (and perhaps things you don't need to know) :p

Comment: Ha ha ha. Ill do that. Upvote for teaching me something **_and_** answering the question. :)

Comment: Sometimes I think the `Community` bot doesnt like me. :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165600/discussion-between-theonewhomade-and-jaromanda-x).